# Unity with google-play-services Social.localUser.Authenticate crash

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, android-unity-plugin

im using unity plugin play-games-plugin-for-unity and natcam

i have to delete google-play-services.jar from natcam.aar to build my project cause i was unable to convert classes into dex format.

after call

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {}
```

my game crash without any transparent reason

```
E/AndroidRuntime(23520): Process: com.trackunload.game, PID: 23520
W/KloServer( 4990): Aborted broadcast does not supprt for: com.trackunload.game
W/ActivityManager( 4219):   Force finishing activity com.trackunload.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
D/AES     ( 4219):     process : com.trackunload.game
D/AES     ( 4219):      module : com.trackunload.game v3 (1.0.2)
D/AEE/LIBAEE( 4219): shell: raise_exp(2, 23520, -1361051648, com.trackunload.game, 0x0x558ffd98c0, 0x0x0)
I/DEBUG   (23669): [OnPurpose Redunant in void preset_info(aed_report_record*, int, int)] pid: 23520, tid: -1361051648, name: UNKNOWN  >>> com.trackunload.game <<<
V/AEE/AED (23669): dashboard_record_update() : rec->module = com.trackunload.game 
V/WindowManager( 4219): Changing focus from Window{3b3dc3b9 u0 com.trackunload.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} to Window{453e7c7 u0 Application Error: com.trackunload.game} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.addWindow:2842 com.android.server.wm.Session.addToDisplay:173 android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView:647 android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView:282 
I/WindowManager( 4219): Gaining focus: Window{453e7c7 u0 Application Error: com.trackunload.game}
I/BufferQueueConsumer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:0,p:-1,c:255) setConsumerName: Application Error: com.trackunload.game
I/BufferQueueConsumer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:0,p:-1,c:255) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1 height=1
I/BufferQueueConsumer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:0,p:-1,c:255) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1920 height=382
I/BufferQueueProducer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:4219,c:255) connect(P): api=1 producer=(4219:system_server) producerControlledByApp=false
I/BufferQueueProducer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:4219,c:255) new GraphicBuffer needed
D/BufferQueueProducer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:4219,c:255) allocateBuffers: allocating from 1 buffers up to 3 buffers
D/BufferQueueProducer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:4219,c:255) allocateBuffers: allocating from 3 buffers up to 3 buffers
W/ActivityManager( 4219): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{3d6b8487 u0 com.trackunload.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t112 f}
I/BufferQueueConsumer(  255): [com.trackunload.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0x55833746c0,id:1186,api:2,p:23520,c:255) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1080 height=1920
I/BufferQueueConsumer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:4219,c:255) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1080 height=382
V/WindowManager( 4219): Changing focus from Window{453e7c7 u0 Application Error: com.trackunload.game} to Window{8c84a90 u0 RecentsPanel} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.addWindow:2842 com.android.server.wm.Session.addToDisplay:173 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:111 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:136 
I/BufferQueueProducer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:-1,c:255) disconnect(P): api 1
I/BufferQueueConsumer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:-1,c:255) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffffffffffff
I/BufferQueueProducer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:4219,c:255) connect(P): api=1 producer=(4219:system_server) producerControlledByApp=false
I/BufferQueueProducer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:4219,c:255) new GraphicBuffer needed
I/BufferQueueProducer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:4219,c:255) new GraphicBuffer needed
V/WindowManager( 4219): Changing focus from Window{8c84a90 u0 RecentsPanel} to Window{453e7c7 u0 Application Error: com.trackunload.game} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:3595 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout:202 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:237 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:136 
I/WindowManager( 4219): Gaining focus: Window{453e7c7 u0 Application Error: com.trackunload.game}
I/BufferQueueProducer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:4219,c:255) new GraphicBuffer needed
I/BufferQueueProducer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:4219,c:255) queueBuffer: fps=3.57 dur=1120.10 max=522.67 min=11.79
W/WindowManager( 4219): Force clearing orientation change: Window{3b3dc3b9 u0 com.trackunload.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
I/WindowManager( 4219): Screen frozen for +2s18ms due to Window{3b3dc3b9 u0 com.trackunload.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
I/BufferQueueProducer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:4219,c:255) queueBuffer: fps=6.67 dur=2548.01 max=2278.98 min=15.41
I/BufferQueueProducer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:-1,c:255) disconnect(P): api 1
I/BufferQueueConsumer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:-1,c:255) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffffffffffff
V/WindowManager( 4219): Changing focus from Window{453e7c7 u0 Application Error: com.trackunload.game EXITING} to Window{e04e2b0 u0 com.nianticlabs.pokemongo/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2975 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2912 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:192 android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow:3344 
I/WindowManager( 4219): Losing focus: Window{453e7c7 u0 Application Error: com.trackunload.game EXITING}
I/WindowState( 4219): WIN DEATH: Window{3b3dc3b9 u0 com.trackunload.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
I/BufferQueueProducer(  255): [com.trackunload.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0x55833746c0,id:1186,api:2,p:-1,c:255) disconnect(P): api 2
D/GuiExt  (  302): [GuiExtS] binder of dump tunnel(BQM-[23520:com.trackunload.game]) died
I/BufferQueueConsumer(  255): [com.trackunload.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0x55833746c0,id:1186,api:2,p:-1,c:255) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffffffffffff
W/WindowManager( 4219): Force-removing child win Window{3e9cdaf2 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{3b3dc3b9 u0 com.trackunload.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
I/ActivityManager( 4219): Process com.trackunload.game (pid 23520) has died
D/ActivityManager( 4219): SVC-handleAppDiedLocked: app = ProcessRecord{1ba87ed8 23520:com.trackunload.game/u0a178}, app.pid = 23520
D/SurfaceFlinger(  255):     remove: com.trackunload.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
I/BufferQueueConsumer(  255): [com.trackunload.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0x55833746c0,id:1186,api:2,p:-1,c:-1) disconnect(C)
I/BufferQueue(  255): [com.trackunload.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](this:0x55833746c0,id:1186,api:2,p:-1,c:-1) ~BufferQueueCore
I/BufferQueueConsumer(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:-1,c:-1) disconnect(C)
I/BufferQueue(  255): [Application Error: com.trackunload.game](this:0x55832155c0,id:1192,api:1,p:-1,c:-1) ~BufferQueueCore
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you added permissions added to manifest?

Comment: Yes (I've got Location permission), but maybe I didnt thought about some of them. Could you say which you mean?

Comment: this may be a silly question but did you build the GooglePlayServices platform before calling .Activate()?

Comment: What do U mean to build the GPS platform in Unity?

Comment: @Ziejer sorry if this is too late, but I think Cabrra meant go to Window -> Google Play Games ->  Setup -> Android Setup